# Unable to run packaged TestMain.java

Tags: java, classpath, package, javac

I am making Java files in my package `programapper`, and have `package programapper;` at the top of every file. One of the files is called `TestMain.java`:

```
package programapper;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class TestMain {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String filename = null;
    System.out.print("File to read: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  }
}
```

Whenever I compile, I run

```
javac -d . *.java
```

This compiles fine and I am left with all of my .java files in my primary Programapper/ directory, and then I have Programapper/programapper, where all of my class files are stored.

I am unable to then load the class and run its main function. I'm using

```
java -classpath .:programapper/ programapper.TestMain
```

and I have also tried using

```
java -classpath .:programapper/ TestMain
```

The error I am receiving is `Error: Could not find or load main class programapper.TestMain`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the class `public`:

```
public class TestMain {
    ...
```

If you omit visibility, the class will be accessible only from the classes within the same package. Which is not sufficient for the main class.

Additionally, instead of specifying just the class name, you need to specify classpath as "." and specify the full class including package:

```
java -classpath . programapper.TestMain
```

Comment: Ah...I figured it out. I was thinking about classpath wrong. Changing it to `java -cp . programapper/TestMain` worked

Comment: lol looks like I figured it out right as you were making that last edit ;)